# How to USE external C functions in Objective-C with UITextField and UITextView ;-)

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch

Again I'm trying to wrap my head around Objective-C and Cocoa. So I've posted some code below. What I'm trying to do is basically use the function "th_brk_line" by entering text into a UITextField then displaying it into a UITextView once it has been processed by "th_brk_line". I've posted the external function definition and the typedef for "thchar_t" as well for clarity,I hope. I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is understanding how this C function would be used in Objective-C as well as a working example with UITextField and UITextView. This is an exercise mainly for my understanding the concept with Objective-C and Cocoa.

Thanks Again!

```
typedef unsigned char thchar_t; 

extern int th_brk_line(const thchar_t *in, thchar_t *out, size_t n, const char *delim);


int main () {

char line [1024];
char bline [1024];

while (fgets (line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    if (line [strlen (line) - 1] == '\n')
        line [strlen (line) - 1] = '\0';

    th_brk_line (line, bline, 1024, "|");
    printf ("% s \n'", bline);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Still a noob? You were a noob yesterday when you asked your first question. My God, man, what have you been _doing_ for the last 24 hours? (in the voice of Leonard McCoy).

Comment: Please edit the title of the question to summarize what you want to know and not what your social status on SO is ;-)

Comment: haha...sorry man! I'm a really SLOW learner!

Comment: Jens - not to be all "Nancy" France. But the "Question" summarizes what i would like to know. I apologize if I wasn't creative enough with the title, but it is within the guidelines/criteria of the "Stackoverflow" faq. I will however take your advice for my next Question. :) thanks!

Comment: I think I'm going to have to find a Stack exchange site to ask the question "What is "Nancy" France?  Which one, God, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, you need to put your text field and your text view on the screen and some sort of button that you press to make the text in the field appear in the view having been processed.  You can use the keyboard's return key to do this.

On the assumption that you have done the above, calling a C function from Objective-C is easy.  It's exactly the same as calling it from C.  The tricky bit is that your function expects a C string as input and gives you a C string as output.  Look in to [NSString -UTF8String](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and NSString +stringWithCString:encoding:

Comment: Thanks! You were correct "tricky!". Still a bit rough, but i'll hack/read/re-hack my way through it until i get it right.